# How to loop VBA code to perform same actions through list of data

Tags: html, excel, vba

Ok, sorry guys... I managed to figure out the issue with regards to clicking the "Next Results" button and looping it back around to pull the same data, then click the "Next Results" button and pull the same data... so on and so on until... and here's where I'm running into the problem. I keep getting an "Object required" error on my "Loop Until" statement... I've tried a number of different workarounds, switching to variables, etc. but still running into errors. Basically I would just like the loop to stop once the "Next Results" button is no longer available (which will obviously happen when there is no more data to pull).

Here's the section of VBA causing the problem...

```
Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim TDelement As HTMLTableCell
Dim r As Long

Set TDelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

r = 0

Do
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    For Each TDelement In TDelements

        If TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsContent" Then
            Sheet1.Range("E1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText
            r = r + 1
        ElseIf TDelement.className = "searchActivityResultsContent" Then
            Sheet1.Range("E1").Offset(r, 0).Value = TDelement.ChildNodes(8).innerText
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    Set elems = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems

    If e.Value = "Next Results" Then
        e.Click
        Exit For
    End If

Next e

Loop Until e.Value <> "Next Results"

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
   DoEvents
Loop

IE.Quit
```

Here's the HTML code for the buttons I'm referring to...

```
<table class="contentTable" align="center">
    <tr class="contentTableTR">
<form name="scrollResultListForm" method="post"   action="/scrollTransactionsList.do" onsubmit="return isBusy();">




<input type="submit" name="action" value="Next Results" onmouseover="showComment(event,'Display next results')" onmouseout="hideComment()" class="formButton">


<input type="submit" name="action" value="Last Page" onmouseover="showComment(event,'Goto last result page')" onmouseout="hideComment()" class="formButton">

</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding the question(s). Do you have difficulties pressing the "Next" button on some website? Is that the question? For learning loops you might want to have a look at the following: http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html

Comment: You could push the "NextResults" button by doing a getElementsByTagName for whatever kind of container it's in and then a loop to get it by searching for innerText = InStr(myElement.innerText, "NextResults"), and then myElement.click

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to push button: 
Try to use the innermost tag type, such as if it's inside an "a" tag inside of a div, use "a"

```
Dim aTag, someTags
Set someTags = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each aTag In someTags
    If InStr(aTag.innerText, "NextResults") Then
       aTag.Click
       Exit For
    End If
Next aTag
```